# Sharepoint 2010 CSOM Object - List Column Type NOTE

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, csom, sharepoint-object-model

In the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client CSOM library in VB.NET, is there a object or set of objects that will allow me to access properties/values and methods on a SharePoint list column of type Note?  I have dug around, but cannot find any documentation on this.  Maybe I'm asking the question wrong.

*IE: for a multi-valued user lookup field, i can use the FieldUserValue class*

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a choose field. The library doesn't offer api calls to access all of the data as it is set to use versioning. I will have to use a web service or workflow to copy the data to an external place (not a good thing).